# Regex for Match DataType and Precision

Tags: regex, regex-group

Suppose that we have the following Strings:

```
NUMBER
NUMBER(10)
```

I need a regex expression that matches theses strings to:

```
NUMBER      => Group(0) = NUMBER
NUMBER(10)  => Group(0) = NUMBER, Group(1) = 10
```

The following expression do this, but it seems a little bit ugly to me:

```
([^[\]]+)\(([^)]+)\)|([^[\]]+)
```

That is translated to 21 steps.
Since I'm not a regex expert, could anybody help me to improve this expression to make it faster?

Comment: First thing to mention is: what is wrong with your expression? Does it return incorrect matches? Then, is there any part of the string that is static? Are there always digits inside parentheses? Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/aZ3lZ3/2). You have not specified the language, BTW, it is important.

Comment: Another thing worthy of note: the number of steps does not directly indicate performance.

Comment: Well, [`(\w+)(?:\((\d+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/aZ3lZ3/3) looks shortest.

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew! Thanks a lot fot your response. My previous was Ok, but I found the number of steps to long. The language is Java.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, what would be your approach to check what expressions is the fastest? Thanks!

Comment: You must create a test case with the pattern and a string that will be matched in a for loop like 50-100,000 times measuring the start nd end time of matching, and then just calculate the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems simpler:

```
([^(]+)(?:\((.+?)\))?
```

Regex101 says 6 steps for `"NUMBER"`, and 13 for `"NUMBER(10)"`.

You could consider adding `^` to the start and `$` to the end to be stricter, in which case the step count goes up by 2 for each input example.